# Issue in laravel relation with multiple or where

Tags: laravel, model, relation

I have issue in user model in laravel relation.i want to use or where but don't know how to use.please look at the code that i know it is wrong but don't know how to use correct one.

```
public function subUsers() {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class,'level1_parent1','id')
                ->orWhere('level2_parent','id')
                ->orWhere('level3_parent','id')
                ->orWhere('level4_parent','id')
                ->orWhere('level5_parent','id')
                ->orWhere('level6_parent','id')
                ->orWhere('level7_parent','id');
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are tying to do with the orWhere is not possible. The orWhere method does not work in the way you are trying to use it when defining relationships. You have to wrap the condition into  aditional closure.

I think this will work:

```
public function subUsers() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class)
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('level1_parent', $this->id)
                  ->orWhere('level2_parent', $this->id)
                  ->orWhere('level3_parent', $this->id)
                  ->orWhere('level4_parent', $this->id)
                  ->orWhere('level5_parent', $this->id)
                  ->orWhere('level6_parent', $this->id)
                  ->orWhere('level7_parent', $this->id);
        });
}
```

Comment: $this->id is showing null.

Comment: Do you have subusers in your database?

Comment: yes level_parent have parent users id's

Comment: @smehsoud if you dd($this) what do you get?

Comment: primaryKey: "id" only nothing else

Comment: Where did you put this function? You have to put this function in the User model. Im asking because you should get a instance of a user. This instance always has a id when its pulled from the database.

Comment: yes it is in user model.